# single app delegate for universal applications

Tags: iphone, delegates, ios-universal-app

I am doing a universal application which has 2 app delegates separately for iPhone and iPad. Can I check the device in a single app delegate using a bool value set to yes something like `BOOL isiPhone` and the method `+(AppDelegate*)instance;`. Then how can I launch different views? I got some code snippet like this

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

UIWindow* window;
BOOL isiPhone;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow* window;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isiPhone;

+ (AppDelegate*)instance;

@end
```

And in the Application's App Delegate m file:

```
@synthesize m_ForIPhone;

self.MapVC = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:(self.isiPhone ? @"MapView" : @"MapView@pad") bundle:nil];
self.DetailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:self.isiPhone ? @"DetailView" : @"DetailView@pad" bundle:nil];

self.AboutVC = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:self.isiPhone ? @"AboutView" : @"AboutView@pad" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Following Code

```
id<UIApplicationDelegate> delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
AppDelegate_iPad *appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPad *) delegate;

else
AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *) delegate;
```

whenever you are required to access to the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the standard way of appending `~ipad` or `~iphone` to the end of your XIB filenames to specify that XIB is for iPad or iPhone respectively.

So you might have:

```
MapView.xib
MapView~ipad.xib

DetailView.xib
DetailView~ipad.xib

AboutView.xib
AboutView~ipad.xib
```

It will pick the most specific one for that platform, so running on the iPhone you'll get `MapView.xib` being loaded whilst on the iPad it will load `MapView~ipad.xib`.

Comment: I was wondering if the same convention works for AppDelegate. Would my main function know which one is for which?

Comment: It works anywhere you use a resource. So, yes, if you use it for `MainWindow.xib` then it will work.